# Most efficient way to filter multiple dimensions

Tags: filter, mdx

Trying to get the [Number] and [Sum of Time Spent] for all Changes that were open during period 201405.

The best definition of open I can think of is is:
    - Changes that were logged before or during the [MonthPeriod], while closed during or after the [MonthPeriod]

```
SELECT
    [Measures].[Sum of Time Spent] ON COLUMNS
    ,
    [FactChange].[Number].[Number] ON ROWS
FROM
    [Change Management]
WHERE
    (FILTER(
            [DimLoggedDate].[MonthPeriod].[MonthPeriod]
            ,[DimLoggedDate].[MonthPeriod].MEMBERVALUE <= 201405
        )
        ,
        FILTER(
            [DimClosedDate].[MonthPeriod].[MonthPeriod]
            ,[DimClosedDate].[MonthPeriod].MEMBERVALUE >= 201405
        ))
```

The above query returns a list with all numbers, with a null value when the filters in the WHERE clause don't apply. I would like to remove the NULL items.

Because the query returns ALL Numbers, I wonder if this is the most efficient query to solve the issue. Applying NonEmpty() would remove the numbers, but since all changes are enumerated, isn't this putting more stress on the system than required?

Answer (score 0):

You do it simply by adding "Non empty" in the on Rows clause:

```
...
non empty [FactChange].[Number].[Number] on Rows
...
```